# Ruby array into an object instance

Tags: ruby, arrays, object

I've made an array generator for fake individuals to populate apartments:

```
["53 York Street", 7995, true, 123, 2, 1, "Tommy Gough"]
["53 York Street", 18070, true, 278, 2, 1, "Sarah Stewart"]
```

but I want to turn each instance into an Object Instance and I'm trying to figure out an .each loop (or other) method to do so. I haven't found a way to write a method that doesn't use a string for output... but I'm probably going about it wrong.

Comment: Do you have a class that has these fields?

Answer (score 1):

Say the class that you want instances of looks something like this:

```
Apartment = Struct.new(:street, :code, :field3, :field4, :field5, :field6, :name)
```

(I don't know what the other fields stand for.)

And say your input looks like this:

```
input = [
  ["53 York Street", 7995, true, 123, 2, 1, "Tommy Gough"],
  ["53 York Street", 18070, true, 278, 2, 1, "Sarah Stewart"]
]
```

Then you can create an array of instances like this:

```
output = input.map { |entry| Apartment.new(*entry) }
```

Note the splat (`*`) that expands the (inner) array to a list of method arguments that you can pass to your constructor. A more verbose way to write this would be:

```
output = []
input.each do |entry|
  output << Apartment.new(*entry)
end
```